# Actions datetimeoffset to local user settings region

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

Please let me know if I am taking the right approach into this matter:

I have a web app and I want show localized actions datetime to user based on his timezone.

For example: user x created this at this date, user y modified this item at this date and so forth.

Is it ok to save all those actions into a `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` type and when shown to user, convert the DateTimeOffset to user local time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take into account

> Although a DateTimeOffset value includes an offset, it is not  a fully
>   time zone-aware data structure. While an offset from UTC is  one
>   characteristic of a time zone, it does not unambiguously  identify a
>   time zone. Not only do multiple time zones share the same  offset from
>   UTC, but the offset of a single time zone changes if it  observes
>   daylight saving time. This means that, as soon as a  DateTimeOffset
>   value is disassociated from its time zone, it can  no longer be
>   unambiguously linked back to its original time zone.

Why don't you go with `DateTime .ToUniversalTime` before saving into the database and then convert to the users local format as you retrieve the data to display it? I think it is a safer option.

Comment: DateTimeOffset can represent the exact same time as DateTime. Thus dateTimeOffsetFromDB.ToUniversalTime.ToAppropriateUserLocalT‌​ime has the same effect, with the benefit of preserving the historical TZ offset information (DST issues still apply, but no more so). Some applications might store a secondary TZ (non-offset field); however, I don't know of a "good reason" why one wouldn't keep as much additional data as possible or, as this answer does, recommend DateTime over DateTimeOffset for user-data datetimes..

Answer (score 2):

First, DateTimeOffset is prefered over DateTime for application development. See this MSDN page: [Choosing Between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, and TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Second, I'd like to point out that if you use DateTime, you HAVE to convert user's input DateTime data to UTC before saving it, so that you can properly convert it to the user's local time later. If you use DateTimeOffset, there is no need to convert to UTC - as long as you ensure both Date and Time components are present. The Date components helps determine whether Daylight Saving is in effect for the user's time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you will register and store the date and time whenever an action is taken. I would register them as `DateTime.UtcNow` every time something happens.

That way you are sure to know when actually something took place without having to worry about the timezone of the user triggering it. That will be the first step. Then you can start thinking about alternatives to how to show them to the user by using the users timezone; which will be easier to do. For this kind of internationalization issues of time, you might consider taking a look on APIs like [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) as well.